# how encoding works on cookie authentication value in servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I'm getting the session Id from the OOB servicestack cookie and grab the IAuthSession from the cache, because I don't have the SS context available.

so far this is what I've done:

```
KeyValuePair<string, Cookie> cookie = Context.Request.Cookies.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Key == "ss-id");
string encodedValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookie.Value.Value, new ASCIIEncoding());
var session = _cacheClient.Get<IAuthSession>(string.Format("urn:iauthsession:{0}", encodedValue));
```

the text encoding isn't the correct since sometimes the encoded text doesn't match the key stored in cache, I've been looking at the code but I haven't found the place where the key gets encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ss-id` cookie is created in [SessionExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/SessionExtensions.cs). The value of the cookie is generated as a random base64 string.

The encoding issue you are seeing is likely because your random base64 includes a `+` and/or `/` symbol when it was generated. This issue has been [fixed by this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/250f1cb6531dad75bc711aeee7ba857c406470a6) in the latest version of ServiceStack available on NuGet 4.0.12, which prevents the creation of session id's with these characters.

If you upgrade to latest version there shouldn't be any encoding issues because the value will only be made up of characters `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9`. So the key would simply be:

```
string.Format("urn:iauthsession:{0}", cookie.Value.Value));
```

Comment: Is there any way to get that sorted on the lastest 3.x version, we plan to migrate to version 4 but not in the near future.